# How to display a progress bar with webview

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, loading, progress

This is my last code and. I want to show user network info. When user is offline alert to the user.
And I want to show to user in offline or online. I use progress bar. When I use this code my Application is crashing and go out of my application. What should I do

```
   ConnectivityManager conMgr;
   NetworkInfo netInfo;
    private WebView webView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

           Toast.makeText(Activity5.this, "welcome",30000).show();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity5.this);
            Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttn1);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Activity5.this, Activity2.class));
                }
            });


            String url = "http://student.iaun.ac.ir";
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Activity5.this, Prefs.class));
                }
        });


            progressDialog.setMessage("please wait web page is loading");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, 25000);

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity5.this);
                if (isOnline()) {
                       /*Your Code*/
                  }
                else{
                   try {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Activity5.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                  try {
                                        startDelay();
                                        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
                                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                        }
            }).start();    

    }



    void startDelay() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }
       private boolean isOnline() {
            conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity1, menu);
        return true;


    }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points are :

1. You can't use System.exit(0) on button click, you can use finish() to complete that activity or moveTaskToBack(true) to minimize the application.
2. [I would like to refer u this link :](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/)
3. Firstly understand every thing, then move forward, not just copy & paste thee code, Understand the concept and logic behind it.
4. If you need more help on this topic then I am here, but take your time and try to understand the logics

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code, now a progress dialog is appear for 20 seconds in the meanwhile the webview is also load its content...

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    private webview webview;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity1.this);
        String url = "http://student.iaun.ac.ir";
        webview = (webview) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }, 20000);



    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
        // to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: i write this code but i want to use thread.sleep in my program what should i do

Comment: Handler is also a thread in android and the second argument of postDelayed() method is the sleep time for it, from this code the line     progressDialog.dismiss(); execaute after 20 seconds...

Comment: no i want to use thread.sleep in my program to setJavaScriptEnabled(true) because i setJavaScriptEnabled(false) at first and after 15 sec setJavaScriptEnabled(true).what should i do

Comment: You just add statement for enable the java script in run() method, if u want a separate thread for that then you can create it anduse sleep for that one

Comment: i want to Add code that show user what is the internet Condition.you use
 alertDialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
in your first cod. i want when user is offline it shows alert
or progress bar

Comment: i use your cod but it is not working.when i use this cod my program is crashing and it goes out.and said"Unfortunately.. has stop
i edit code in my Question.you can see my cod in my question

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WebViewClient, and override the method onPageStarted(), onpageFinished() etc...

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
        private WebView browser;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        ConnectivityManager conMgr;
        NetworkInfo netInfo;
        String url;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_activity);
            browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.shop);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
            if (isOnline()) {
                browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                browser.loadUrl(/*Your url paste here*/);
                browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                            Bitmap favicon) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                try {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            WebActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isOnline() {
            conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && browser.canGoBack()) {
                browser.goBack();
                return true;
            } else {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code to check user network status...

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr;
NetworkInfo netInfo;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_activity);
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.shop);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
            if (isOnline()) {
                   /*Your Code*/
              }
            else{
               try {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    WebActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

and this is the isOnline() method to check status...

```
private boolean isOnline() {
        conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Android: I use this code but it does not work and program is crash

Comment: @user3051593: I use this code but it does not work and program is crash

Comment: You just need a alert dialog until your webpage is finish loading, so you just use WebViewClient, it will solve your problem, can you tell me what exactly the error is(from your logcat).

Comment: eclipse dos not have error.when i run program it is crash and said Unfortunately ,web has stopped and get out program.can you type write code my web view cod is you can see the txt of my code in notepad http://upload.tehran98.com/upme/uploads/19dc061db3f3ddf31.rar

Comment: You just remove the countdowntimer and where is your WebView instance, The link provided by you is invalid...

Comment: I change code from my Question to the WebView code you can see it in my Question .if you can edit my code with showing progress bar in for 20 sec

Comment: But it works for me, can you tell me what exactly the error is, Pls Go to    windows>show view>other>logcat(look at the red lines)

Comment: it does not have red line in running program it has crash and go out of my program

Comment: i write my code in Question.you can copy to your project and see the result.my program is running but when it is run it is crashing